# how to display XML format data in TextArea in flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I am having a function returning an XML tree structure , I wish to display the whole tree in an TextArea in flex.
Here is the code:

```
    <mx:Button id="button1" label="Submit" width="100" click="mainTxt.text=myemp.input_data(args);" />
```

input_data() returns XML tree .How do I send it to mainTxt TextArea ?
I have tried using mainTxt.html as well.

-BHU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    protected function onButton1ClickHandler(event:MouseEVent):void
    {
        trace(myemp.input_data(args));
        var xmlStr:XML = myemp.input_data(args);
        mainTxt.text = xmlStr.toString();
    }    
]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:Button id="button1"
           label="Submit"
           width="100"
           click="onButton1ClickHandler(event)" />
```

first check this **trace()** if this will print correct XML-tree then you have answer.

May this will help...

Comment: i tried this answer. But my flash debugger is not configured.I created mm.cfg file and then created flashlog.txt as well. is there any other thing i should do.I executed the program ,flashlog.txt is empty.